# Jenkins change choice parameter value automatically based on the week day

Tags: jenkins, configuration, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In my jenkins job, I have a choice parameter containing 4 values (val1, val2, val3, val4).

Is it possible to set dynamically the choice parameter value based on a recurrent temporal event?

More precisely, I would like to change dynamically this value every Monday of the year.

For example:

```
Monday March 16 => it takes val1 
Monday March 23 => it takes val2 
Monday March 30 => it takes val3 
Monday April 6  => it takes val4 
Monday April 13 => it takes val1
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you have the Active Choice plugin installed?

Comment: I don't think Active Choice supports this @MattSchuchard

Comment: You need it to extend the parameters class to dynamically generate these choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your question basically boils down to two:

1. How can I programmatically determine which value to select, based on current date?
2. Having that figured out, how can I cause that value to be the default in the `choice` parameter of the pipeline?

Considering you're doing fine by yourself with #1 (may include getting the week number and taking the remainder of that divided by 4), let's tackle the second question.

To modify the `choices` parameter based on the result of some arbitrary Groovy script, you may want to run a scripted pipeline before your declarative one, something like this:

```
def use_as_default = getValToUseAsDefault() // val1 on March 16, etc.

def list_of_vals = []

list_of_vals += use_as_default // first in the list will get to be selected

if (! ("val1" in list_of_vals) ) { list_of_vals += "val1"}
if (! ("val2" in list_of_vals) ) { list_of_vals += "val2"}
if (! ("val3" in list_of_vals) ) { list_of_vals += "val3"}
if (! ("val4" in list_of_vals) ) { list_of_vals += "val4"}

list_of_vals = Arrays.asList(list_of_vals)

pipeline
{
    agent any

    parameters
    {
        choice(name: 'VALS', choices: list_of_vals, description: 'Choose value')
    }
...
}

def getValToUseAsDefault() {
   // left as exercise to OP
   return "val1"
}
```

Comment: You might want to ask a question "How do I get a week number using Groovy".